# Laravel "405 Method Not Allowed" on CCAvenue response return URL callback

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, ccavenue

I am adding CcAvenue gateway in laravel 5.3 on PHP 7.2, everything working fine till the payment page of CcAvenue, but after payment is done or payment canceled by the user, the return response URL is showing the following error

"Oops! An Error Occurred
The server returned a "405 Method Not Allowed".
Something is broken. Please let us know what you were doing when this error occurred. We will fix it as soon as possible. Sorry for any inconvenience caused."

My return URL is this: https:// [www.domainname.com/booking/cancel/cc_checkout_gateway?c=f4b7d25d6e894a44725fff59adafcf82](http://www.domainname.com/booking/cancel/cc_checkout_gateway?c=f4b7d25d6e894a44725fff59adafcf82)

Code in the Routes file

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
// Booking
Route::group(['prefix'=>config('booking.booking_route_prefix')],function(){
    Route::post('/addToCart','BookingController@addToCart');
    Route::post('/doCheckout','BookingController@doCheckout')->name('booking.doCheckout');
    Route::get('/confirm/{gateway}','BookingController@confirmPayment');
    Route::get('/cancel/{gateway}','BookingController@cancelPayment');
    Route::get('/{code}','BookingController@detail');
    Route::get('/{code}/checkout','BookingController@checkout');
    Route::get('/{code}/check-status','BookingController@checkStatusCheckout');

    //ical
    Route::get('/export-ical/{type}/{id}','BookingController@exportIcal')->name('booking.admin.export-ical');
    //inquiry
    Route::post('/addEnquiry','BookingController@addEnquiry');
});
Route::group(['prefix'=>'gateway'],function(){
    Route::get('/confirm/{gateway}','NormalCheckoutController@confirmPayment')->name('gateway.confirm');
    Route::get('/cancel/{gateway}','NormalCheckoutController@cancelPayment')->name('gateway.cancel');
    Route::get('/info','NormalCheckoutController@showInfo')->name('gateway.info');
});
```

Code in BookingController.php

```
 public function cancelPayment(Request $request, $gateway)
    {

        $gateways = get_payment_gateways();
        if (empty($gateways[$gateway]) or !class_exists($gateways[$gateway])) {
            return $this->sendError(__("Payment gateway not found"));
        }
        $gatewayObj = new $gateways[$gateway]($gateway);
        if (!$gatewayObj->isAvailable()) {
            return $this->sendError(__("Payment gateway is not available"));
        }
       
        return $gatewayObj->cancelPayment($request);
    }
```

Code in Gateway CcCheckoutGateway.php

```
public function cancelPayment(Request $request)
    {
        
        
        $c = $request->query('c');
        $booking = Booking::where('code', $c)->first();
        
        if (!empty($booking) and in_array($booking->status, [$booking::UNPAID])) {
            $payment = $booking->payment;
            
            if ($payment) {
                $payment->status = 'cancel';
                $payment->logs = \GuzzleHttp\json_encode([
                    'customer_cancel' => 1
                ]);
                
                $payment->save();

                // Refund without check status
                $booking->tryRefundToWallet(false);
            }
           
           return redirect($booking->getDetailUrl())->with("error", __("You cancelled the payment"));
        }
        
        if (!empty($booking)) {
            return redirect($booking->getDetailUrl());
       } else {
           return redirect(url('/'));
       }
    }
```

After too much R&D I found that my routes code is allowing method is GET & HEAD, but Ccavenue response URL is sending the response in POST method

I have tried every possible solution changed
Route::get('/cancel/{gateway}','BookingController@cancelPayment');

to
Route::post('/cancel/{gateway}','BookingController@cancelPayment');

and
Route::any('/cancel/{gateway}','BookingController@cancelPayment');

but after that it showing error 419: page expired

Please tell me how can I resolve the above issue.

Comment: Check the type of request the CCAvenue is using to hit the URL and then change the same on your route, i.e. `get`, `put`, `post` in your routes file.

Comment: ccavenue will send data over POST.

Answer (score 0):

1, **Route** should accept post request. (resolves 405)

```
Route::match(['get','post'], '/cancel/{gateway}', 'BookingController@cancelPayment');
```

2, Disable **CSRF** validation (resolves 419)

Goto **app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php** and add the route in $except array

```
protected $except = [ '/cancel/*', ];
```